# How to make a true selector for listview item?

Tags: android

I have made a ListView with custom adapter; Now when I click on ListView item this element won't be selected. Therefore I have made a selector and have added it to listview also:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" />
</selector>

list.setSelector(R.layout.custom_item_selector);
```

But now all listview will be a green by click. Please, tell me how can I set a green color for a item selected?

Answer (score 0):

try setcachehint color int he get view method